# Saving a zipfile into directory using django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, zip, python-zipfile

I am trying to save the zip file into one directory on my server.

First, I am uploading a zip file using form and in python, I want to save it in one directory for further use.

I got some piece of code after googling

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

def processZipFile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['frmUploadZipFile']:
        frmUploadZipFile = request.FILES['frmUploadZipFile']
        zipf = ZipFile(frmUploadZipFile, 'w')
        zipdir('/data/apps/nms/maps/', zipf)

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Finally, after running this, I am getting some `_ApRssiStore.txt` file inserted in that folder. But not the zip file. I don't know whats happening in between.

```
**Updated**
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are doing here. If all you want to do is to upload a zip file and save it somewhere, then none of that code is appropriate. You should read the [docs on uploading files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/); the fact that it is a zip file seems irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Updated the code. Please check

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you think you need to create a ZipFile object, or do all that os.walk stuff. None of that has anything to do with uploading a file, which is documented in the link I gave above.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Please forget about the Zipfile. I didn't understand from the doc. Just give me a small line which do the file save operation with arguements - path and file.

Comment: Once again, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) which explain exactly this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, will that upload a zip file?